# the_post_thumbnail unless video id is added

Tags: php, loop, post-thumbnails, advanced-custom-fields

I have 2 choices on the edit post page to insert an video ID from either vimeo or youtube. The user needs to select, with a select field (channel), if he wants to embed video from one or the other.

```
<?php if (get_field('channel') == 'Youtube') {
        echo get_field('youtube_video_id');
    }
    if (get_field('channel') == 'Vimeo') {
        echo get_field('vimeo_video_id');
    }
?>
```

Now I'd like this to overrule the_post_thumbnail. So when a video is posted is shows the video instead of the thumb. Is that possible?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    *** MAGIC HERE I GUESS? ***

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Nothing here</p>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope somebody can push me in the right direction. Or am I doing this the other way arround? I'm my PHP is still a learning curve.

Thanks, 
/Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  if (get_field('channel') == 'Youtube') {
    echo get_field('youtube_video_id');
  } elseif (get_field('channel') == 'Vimeo') {
    echo get_field('vimeo_video_id');
  } elseif ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
  }
```

That should use a Youtube video, then a Vimeo video, then the thumbnail, and do nothing otherwise.

Comment: ah thanks, I'm on my phone atm, will check tomorrow and accept.